# Scraping website post data with PHP

Tags: php, dom, curl, screen-scraping, postdata

I have a website that want to scrap
www.tiketux.com
And I want fill this form so I can get data in 
www.tiketux.com/book/pilihjadwal

I found this post data like this
https://www.tiketux.com/book/pilihjadwal/post?agen=CPG&keberangkatan=0004&tujuan=153&jumpenumpang=1&datepicker=15%2F10%2F2014&idJurusan=153&kotaAsal=Bandung

In that page we can found the travel schedule
I try using DOM and cURL but that data can't load,,
Someone can help me how to get that data?

Thanks

Comment: Post or Get?  Either way you're question is too general and not fit for SO.

Comment: I mean I want get that travel schedule data

Comment: Well like I said, it looks like a GET request not a POST, and it is too general.  Contract it out if you need help with the entire project, otherwise SO is for specific questions/errors.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $options = array(
        'http' => array(
            'header'  => "Content-type: text/html;charset=UTF-8\r\n",
            'method'  => 'POST',
            'content' => http_build_query([]),
        )
    );

    $context  = stream_context_create($options);

    $result = file_get_contents('https://www.tiketux.com/book/pilihjadwal/post?agen=CPG&keberangkatan=0004&tujuan=153&jumpenumpang=1&datepicker=15%2F10%2F2014&idJurusan=153&kotaAsal=Bandung', false, $context);

    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    @$doc->loadHTML($result);
```

$doc will be DOM-document from URL. Manual: http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Comment: I get error on http_build_query,, Did I miss some code there? what code can I add there? thanks

Comment: which error did you get? write text of error please